# ssh-copy-id -- send pubkey to other location then ~/.ssh/auhtorized_keys?

Tags: ssh, scp

I want to acces a remote server via ssh which has set the location for authorized keys set as `/path/to/ssh/authorized_keys.%u`.

Now I am wondering how I can motivate `ssh-copy-id` to create an `authorized_keys` file at that location following that naming convention.

I tried `ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/id_rsa.pub username@[ip-addresse] -o /path/to/ssh/authorized_key.username` but that gives me an error:

`ERROR: command-line: line 0: Bad configuration option: /path/to/ssh/authorized_keys.username`

writing this I wonder whether scp alernatively might provide a solution (couln't say how exactly though).

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 0):

[`ssh-copy-id`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_8_4_P1/contrib/ssh-copy-id) cannot install public keys to a user provided file. `.ssh/authorized_keys`  (or `/etc/dropbear/authorized_keys` for a dropbear server). You could contribute an option to allow the user to provide this, but will be some time before such a patch is accepted upstream and downstream.

When the user has a complete `authorized_keys` locally, they can upload that with `sftp`. Less useful if they do not know all the keys needed, and might lock someone out if some are omitted.

Alternatively, configure sshd so users don't need to upload their keys to each host. Consider `AuthorizedKeysCommand` that looks up keys from some system, whether a fancy FreeIPA or something simpler like downloading from some web server.

Comment: thks for clarifying. Indeed that would be a nice contribution. I am not capable to provide such a PR though, I am afraid.